# Fatal error: Function name must be a string doctrine and Zend 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have class contains Foreign key and i want insert this foreign key in my class

I do that script with doctrine 2 and zend 2 :

```
$geographicalarea = new Geographicalarea();
$geographicalarea = $entityManager()->getRepository('\Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea')->find (array('idGeographicalArea'=> $idgeographicalarea ));

echo "Create ";
$department = new Department();
$department->setNamedepartment($data ['nameDepartment']);
$department->setCodedepartment($data ['codeDepartment']);
$department->setIdfkgeographicalarea($geographicalarea);
```

and I get this Error :

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\wamp\www\imprimvert\module\Synchro\src\Synchro\Service\DepartmentManager.php
>   on line 88

```
$geographicalarea = $entityManager()->getRepository('\Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea')->find (array('idGeographicalArea'=> $idgeographicalarea ));
```

how can I resolved that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doctrine repositories use the magic `__call()` method to proxy to find* methods, could be it's choking on the space in your method call. Try removing the space at this point `)->find (array(` so it reads like this `)->find(array(`

Comment: always i have the same Error i deleted the space between find but i have the same Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `$entityManager()` but I bet `$entityManager` is an object.

Remove the brackets `()`:

```
$geographicalarea = $entityManager->getRepository('\Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea')->find (array('idGeographicalArea'=> $idgeographicalarea ));
```